# CRTP. Trying to understand an given example

Tags: c++, c++11, crtp

While I was trying to understand CRTP, I came across this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19311411/2293156), where it is a bit fuzzy to me. I can achieve the same results if I do something simpler like this:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    void method() {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->method();
    }
};

class Derived1 // : public Base<Derived1>   <-- commented inherintance
{
public:
    void method() {
        std::cout << "Derived1 method" << std::endl;
    }
};


class Derived2 // : public Base<Derived2>   <-- commmented inherintance
{
public:
    void method() {
        std::cout << "Derived2 method" << std::endl;
    }
};


#include "crtp.h"
int main()
{
    Derived1 d1;
    Derived2 d2;
    d1.method();
    d2.method();
    return 0;
}
```

My question is: what is the purpose of CRTP here? After thought a bit I guess this use is to allow something like this:

```
template<typename T>
void call(Base<T>& x)
{
    x.method();
}
```

and call it like this

```
int main()
{
    Derived1 d1;
    Derived2 d2;

   call(d1);
   call(d2)
}
```

Am I correct?

Comment: CRTP is useful when you need to know the derived type in the parent class at compile-time; when for whatever reason virtual inheritance cannot meet your needs. The other name for this is _static polymorphism_ - you might find more information on that subject rather than CRTP which is more a means to an end.

Comment: You're right. That's a terrible example for CRTP.

Comment: @XerenNarcy My fault. I hadn't fully read the comments section of original question. What I want to know is said by Etherealone when he says: "Bad example. This code could be done with no vtables without using CRTP. **What vtables truly provide is using the base class (pointer or reference) to call derived methods. You should show how it is done with CRTP here**". This what I want to know

Comment: @Amadeus noted, no worries. I've put up another answer hopefully explaining the situation a bit better than before (hard to avoid the verbosity since _some_ background info seems like a must).

Answer (score 1):

> After thought a bit I guess this use is to allow something like this:
>
> ```
> template<typename T>
> void call(Base<T>& x)
> {
>     x.method();
> }
> ```
>
> and call it like this
>
> ```
> int main()
> {
>     Derived1 d1;
>     Derived2 d2;
>
>     call(d1);
>     call(d2);
> }
> ```

You are correct, this is one possible way to use the CRTP example provided.

However it must be noted - as you have - that the example's `main()` shows a poor use-case as it is given (calling the derived methods directly) since we do not need CRTP or inherited methods for the example to work.

---

Regarding this:

> What vtables truly provide is using the base class (pointer or reference) to call derived methods. You should show how it is done with CRTP here.

To appreciate this it's prudent to explain *why* we would want polymorphism in the first place. Before anything else that must be understood, or CRTP looks like nothing more than a neat trick with templates.

Your initial guess is spot on - you would want polymorphism when you want to access behavior / a method of a derived class, that overrides (or defines) behavior that we *need available via the base class*.

In ordinary inheritance like this:

```
struct A { void method() {} };
struct B : A { void method() {} };
int main () {
    B b;
    b.method();
    return 0;
}
```

What happens is `B::method()` is fired, yes, but had we omitted `B::method()` then it would be actually calling `A::method()`. In this sense `B::method()` *overrides* `A::method()`.

If we wanted to call `B::method()`, but only had an `A` object, this is insufficient:

```
int main () {
    B b;
    A *a = &b;
    a->method(); // calls A::method();
    return 0;
}
```

There are two ways to achieve this (at least): *dynamic polymorphism* or *static polymorphism*.

#### Dynamic Polymorphism

```
struct A1 {
    virtual ~A1(){}
    virtual void method() {}
};
struct B1 : A1 {
    virtual ~B1(){}
    virtual void method() override {}
};
int main () {
    B1 b;
    A1 *a = &b;
    a->method(); // calls B1::method() but this is not known until runtime.
    return 0;
}
```

In detail, because `A1` has virtual methods, there exists a special table (the `vtable`) for this class where a function pointer is stored for every virtual method. This function pointer can be overridden by derived classes (in a sense), which is what every instance of `B1` does - sets to it `B1::method`.

Because this information exists at runtime, the compiler doesn't need to know any more than to look up the function pointer for `A1::method` and call whatever it points to, whether its `A1::method` or `B1::method`. Conversely because it's done at runtime the process tends to be slower than knowing the type beforehand...

#### Static Polymorphism

The same example re-done in a way that avoids the use of a vtable:

```
template < class T > struct A2 {
    void method() {
        T *derived_this = static_cast<T*>(this);
        derived_this->method();
    }
};
struct B2 : A2 < B2 > {
    void method() {}
};
int main () {
    B2 b;
    A2<B2> *a = &b; // typically seen as a templated function argument
    a->method(); // calls B2::method() statically, known at compile-time
    return 0;
}
```

This time we're not using dynamic lookups of anything, the exact same behavior is seen using templates and works with *template argument type deduction* as per your example function `template<class T> call(Base<T>*);`

The main difference between the two methods is *when* the resolution from `A::method` to `B::method` using `A*` type is performed. CRTP allows the compiler to know about this derived method since we're using templates to swap from a base to a derived type - hence *static* polymorphism. A `vtable` is employed with virtual functions / methods, and "performs the swap" (wrong but helps to think of it that way) indirectly, by storing a function pointer to the correct class's method.

What @Etherealone was asking the answerer (real word?) is to demonstrate what I've just shown in the above - how CRTP can be used to invoke derived-class methods using a base class pointer, instead of relying on the `vtable` (a layer of indirection to achieve the same, without knowing the derived type itself in the calling code).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the template function "call" can do the same job. But CRTP sometimes might be the better.
usage for example:

```
     Base<Derived1> *d1 = new Derived1;
     d1->method();
```

Comment: That is no different from what I have posted. You can call `d1.method_imp()` and `d2.method_imp()`, after you have commented out the inheritance part. I want to know how CRTP is usually called in main function, for example.